# jQuery change font-family with a quoted variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to apply this CSS with jQuery:

```
font-family: 'VARIABLE FONT', sans-serif;
```

Variable is named `font`, it needs to be in quotes because some fonts have spaces, and I also need to set a fallback **sans-serif** font.

I've been at this for a long time now, so hopefully some one here can help!

For example the following doesn't work:

```
$("#something").css('font-family', '"' + font + '", sans-serif');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use template literals:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
$("#something").css('font-family', `"${font}", sans-serif`);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing "template literals" to me, I had never heard about it before.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you can achieve what you are trying to do.

```
$font = $(".fontFamily").text();
$("#something").css("font-family",$font);
```